# 1 array containing 2 or more equal elements PHP

Tags: php, html

There are many questions about comparing 2 arrays having the same value or checking if a value in array exists, but I can't find this question anywhere:

How can i check if a certain Variable/Value exist twice or more in one array?

Eg:

```
$array_to_check = array( "this", "this" , "yes" , "no" , "maybe" , "yes" , "yes" );

$this_value = "this";

// how to check if $this_value or 'this' value exist more than twice in $array_to_check array:
// if it exist more than twice, echo yes it exist more than once!!
```

it would also be nice to see if there is a function that can be called where I can just insert the variable to check and the array to check as the parameters and return true if the variable value exist more than twice inside the array.

Eg:

```
$function check_if_more_than_two($the_variable_to_check, $array_to_check)
```

thank you so much. any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_keys function has a search facility

All you have to do is count the number of results

```
count(array_keys($array_to_check, $this_value));
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from @pvnarula's answer, but with improved performance:

```
function array_has_dupes($array) {
    return count($array) !== count(array_flip($array));
}
```

[`array_flip`](http://php.net/array-flip) has the convenient effect of "collapsing" duplicate values, but without having to check it for equality against all other values. Something to do with how the array is saved, accessed, etc. Note however that this will only work for arrays of strings and/or numbers, not nested arrays or anything more complicated.

Performance stats:

- `array_unique`: 1,000,000 iterations in 2.38407087326s
- `array_flip`: 1,000,000 iterations in 1.63431406021s

---

EDIT: Having re-read the question, I realise that this is not what is being asked for! Still useful to know, though, so I'll leave it there.

As for actually answering the question, [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array-keys) is the best option, counting the returned array and checking if it has at least 2 items:

```
function array_has_dupes($array,$value) {
    return count(array_keys($array,$value)) > 1;
}
```

Comment: should be more then 2 actually, according to the question

Comment: @Ziarno "twice or more" translates to `>= 2` or `> 1` (identical meaning since we're working in ℕ∪{0})

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_if_more_than_two($the_variable_to_check, $array_to_check) {
  $values_array= array_count_values($array_to_check);
  if ($values_array[$the_variable_to_check] > 2 ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `function check_if_more_than_two` (without `$`)

Answer (score 1):

Use the php function `array_keys`. to get the desired output.

```
$array_to_check = array( "this", "this" , "yes" , "no" , "maybe" , "yes" , "yes" );

$this_value = "this";

if (count(array_keys($array_to_check, $this_value)) > 2) {

     echo "Yes";
}
```